# Why Azure Pipelines parameters dropdown is not showing?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm trying to create an Azure Pipeline that contains a parameter with a set of pre-defined values.
YAML:

```yaml
- name: environment
  type: string
  default: Staging
  values:
  - Staging
  - Production
  - Placeholder1
  - Placeholder2
```

I have values `Placeholder1` and `Placeholder2` because I've seen in one of the questions that Azure must have at least 4 values to show a dropdown.

The parameter is defined in a **template**. Could that be the issue?

Looking at [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script) I should be seeing not the dropdown, but at least a combo box:
[image]

But in my case there is nothing:

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Runtime parameters defined in the template YAML files will not be visible on the UI when manually triggering the pipeline.

You need to define the Runtime parameters in the main YAML file (i.e., **`azure-pipelines.yml`**) so that they can be visible on the UI when manually triggering the pipeline.

Comment: Thank you! I got it working. Now I use `parameters` section in the main pipeline and pass the value to template like this: `extends: template: pr-migrations-pipeline.yaml@templates parameters: environment: ${{ parameters.environment }}`